# How to move Oracle VirtualBox linked-clone machine to a new location?

Tags: virtualbox, clone

My linked-clone machine stop working after I move them from default location, eg. `C:\Users\Nam Gi VU\VirtualBox VMs`, to my usb hard-disk.

Please help me to move them out of there. Thank you!

I got the below error when doing so.

[image]

Comment: Please don't create new tags unless you really have to. Tagging with `virtualbox` is mostly sufficient here. Same goes for your other "extension pack" question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is basically "file not found" from searching for the hard drive based on the current config. VirtualBox stores the full path to the VM's hard drive in a few places. After moving things to a new location and before restarting, you'll need to change the hard drive location thru the VirtualBox Manager. Select the current VM, then `Settings` -> `Storage`. Delete the entry for the current hard drive and then click the "plus" icon to re-add it from its new location. Use the same controller (IDE or SATA) as previously used.
[image: VirtualBox Manager disk configuration section]

Comment: +1. If there are any snapshots involved, there may be some XML hacking necessary, too.

Comment: @RandolphWest Would you help me to do that `xml hack`? I ofcourse had snapshots invlved the linked-clone machine

Comment: Um ... I got it to work, but through trial and error, and reading the errors very carefully. Took me about an hour and I never made notes at the time.

Comment: All paths are stored in the original VM's .vbox file (as xml). The clone only stores an image ID.